# Why can't I add this feed to the RSS widget?

Tags: widgets, rss, feed

I wish to use the following RSS in my widget, but it seems to not pick it up:

http://www.tapuz.co.il/blog/rssBlog.asp?FolderName=TickTack

I imagine there is a problem in the feed.  So:

- What is it?
- And can it be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you leave some feedback for this question or some of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can test with the plugin RSSImport, this has two different parser and more flexibility and also an debug-function for locate problems. The feed ist valid and I think, you must use this with a widget.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use it in RSS widget in my local test stack just fine.

According to [feed validator](http://feedvalidator.org/) it has some issues, but overall valid.

Are there any error messages or how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: I simply saved the widget, but didn't see it on screen.  The caching plugin I have doesn't cache for logged in users...

Comment: Does RSS widget work with any other feed for you? Is there any output at all in page source where widget should be, but not appearing?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Feedburner feed out of it and then add the RSS URL of the "new" feed to your blog. Feedburner normalizes feeds on the fly so this probably just prevents you having any problems with it. The downside is, that Feedburner caches for about 30 minutes or so. If you want it more "fresh", then this solution is not helping you. Another downside is, that it needs manual work. But probably that's not an issue for you.